# Bamboo command line issue

Tags: cmd, bamboo

I have created `run.bat` file that contains the command:

```
C:\sym\symchk.exe /os /if C:\work\chrome.dll /su SRV*C:\work\67.0.3396.99_x64\*http://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com.
```

Then I have created bamboo `task:Command` with parameter `run.bat` added.

This task failed. On using **HttpAnalyzer** I could see that it doesn't even try to connect to link from command line.

Last, running `run.bat` from `cmd.exe` manually works as expected. I see http request in **HttpAnalyzer**, it downloads the pdb file successfully.

Comment: I have tried to run this command in Bamboo development version (http://localhost:6990/bamboo),works as expected, it downloads the pdb file successfully

Comment: I have found it works if tomcat8.exe run as console,by instalation it run as service.

Comment: Solved by run this command in current user session,by default, task runs in session 0.